# I cannot set "-fx-text-fill: white" to external css to style Text nested in a GridPane nested in an Accordion in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

I have been searching the internet and asking many for help with this problem. I am trying to set the "-fx-text-fill" for a Text component nested within a Girdpane, nested within a TitledPane, nested within an accordion for Javafx. I want to style the text (and other things such as a label component) as the accordion is a dynamically updated list. Nothing I do works.

I have tried editing the style sheet by using: text.setStyle(); and I have tried adding css to the css file which is properly linked.

Java code for populating the accordion:

```java
private void populateAccordion(){
        final String[] imageNames = new String[]{"Discord 1", "Discord 2", "Discord 3"};
        final TitledPane[] tps = new TitledPane[imageNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i++) {
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            grid.setVgap(4);
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
            Text infractions = new Text("Infractions: ");
            Text zero = new Text("0");
            zero.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white");
            grid.add(infractions, 0, 0);
            grid.add(zero, 1, 0);
            grid.add(new Label("Cc: "), 0, 1);
            grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
            grid.add(new Label("Subject: "), 0, 2);
            grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 2);
            System.out.println("Printing css of grid");
            grid.getStyleClass().forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println("All done!");
            tps[i] = new TitledPane(imageNames[i],grid);
            tps[i].getChildrenUnmodifiable().forEach(child -> {
                System.out.print(child.getId());
            });
        }
```

Css code for styling the text in the accordion:

```css
.accordion > .titled-pane > .content >  GridPane{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.scroll-pane > .accordion > .titled-pane > .content > GridPane{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.titled-pane > .content > GridPane{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Result:
https://gyazo.com/225a65f0123e82a3b6e818d47afc760c

Expected result:
the text for:
"infractions: 0", "cc", and "subject" should be white
I am wondering if there is a site dedicated to showing the structure of JavaFX elements so I can easily see the structure of these elements and style them accordingly.
I have tried following this site:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled
As well as the modena.css that is used by default:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470/raw/e526d5c54bd145c58409ad3a2b8acb77d90dcbe5/modena.css

Comment: That "site" exists, it is called Scenic View. See [link](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view). Download the version depending if you are using Java 8, 9 or 11.

Comment: I am already using it, the issue is that it doesn't help in my case as it does not show the css class and sub class names.

Comment: That should work, Scenic View is really useful precisely for showing the hierarchy of nodes in the scene graph and for getting the css style classes that each node has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is your `infractions` and `zero` are a `Text`, not a `Label`. If you take a look at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), you'll see the `-fx-text-fill` property is defined for:

- [`Labeled`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled)
- [`TextInputControl`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textinputcontrol)

A `Text` node is neither a `Labeled` nor a `TextInputControl`. The [CSS documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text) doesn't seem to make this clear, but `Text` extends from `Shape` and thus has [the properties](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape) of `Shape`. To change the text color of a `Text` node you should use `-fx-fill`. Alternatively, you could call `text.setFill(...)` in Java code.

I also believe you need to target the `Label`s and `Text` specifically from within the CSS file. You could give your `Label`s a unique style class, same with the `Text`, and use that from the style sheet. Something like:

```css
.white-label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.white-text {
    -fx-till: white;
}
```

Adding a style class looks like:

```
label.getStyleClass().add("white-label");
text.getStyleClass().add("white-text");
```

If needed, you can still make the selection more specific (i.e. `.titled-pane > .content > etc...`).

---

Regarding your question about tool(s) to view the scene graph structure, once such tool is [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view). Make sure you download the correct version to use with your version of Java. You can also use the CSS Analyzer of [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). To show the analyzer, go to "View" → "Show CSS Analyzer" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Windows).